# I have written the write code right still giving error in hackerrank

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list

Solution : Compare Two LinkedList

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

static class SinglyLinkedListNode {
    public int data;
    public SinglyLinkedListNode next;
    public SinglyLinkedListNode(int nodeData) {
        this.data = nodeData;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

static class SinglyLinkedList {
    public SinglyLinkedListNode head;
    public SinglyLinkedListNode tail;

    public SinglyLinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
    }

    public void insertNode(int nodeData) {
        SinglyLinkedListNode node = new SinglyLinkedListNode(nodeData);

        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = node;
        }

        this.tail = node;
    }
}

public static void printSinglyLinkedList(SinglyLinkedListNode node, String sep, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter) throws IOException {
    while (node != null) {
        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(node.data));

        node = node.next;

        if (node != null) {
            bufferedWriter.write(sep);
        }
    }
}

// Complete the compareLists function below.

/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * SinglyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     SinglyLinkedListNode next;
 * }
 *
 */

static boolean compareLists(SinglyLinkedListNode head1, SinglyLinkedListNode head2) { 
    // while((head1 != null && head2 != null) && (head1.data == head2.data)){
    //     head1 = head1.next;
    //     head2 = head2.next;
    // }
    // return (head1 == null && head2 == null);
    
    // }
    
    while((head1!=null && head2!=null) && head1.data == head2.data){
        head1 = head1.next;
        head2 = head2.next;
    }
    return (head1 == null && head2 == null);

}
```

}

Error:-  Below error is coming every time

```
Solution.java:85: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                         ^

Solution.java:87: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                  ^

Solution.java:90: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        int tests = scanner.nextInt();
        ^

Solution.java:91: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
        ^

Solution.java:93: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        for (int testsItr = 0; testsItr < tests; testsItr++) {
        ^
```

Please help to solve this error.

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  What does your question have to do with Digital Signature Algorithm?  -- *DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) is a public-key signature algorithm defined by NIST. Do NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions.*

Comment: I must get new glasses, I cannot see anything like `private static final Scanner` (from the error message) in posted code... No, not my glasses, even copy&pasting it to an editor, I am unable to find the code from the error message! Maybe you should post the relevant code or even better a [mre] (by the error message, apparently there is some code declared **outside** of a class, interface or enum... but we cannot see that)

Comment: You have more closing braces than opening braces. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: also note that you included only 80 lines of code, but the error starts at line 85 (`Solution.java:85: error:...`)

Answer (score 0):

The error does not complain about a line in *your* `compareLists` code, but in the host's code, i.e. in the boilerplate code that is presented to you when you start introducing your function's code.

Your code is thus embedded in the framework's code, that already provided the code for `SinglyLinkedListNode`, `SinglyLinkedList`, ...etc. Also *after* your function `compareLists` there is more boilerplate code that follows: this is code that will actually run the tests.

All this code -- the boilerplate code and your `compareLists` function -- are part of the `Solution` class.

And here comes the problem: you have closed the `Solution` class with a closing brace. This means that the boilerplate code that *follows* it, suddenly finds itself outside of the `Solution` class, which is a syntax error.

The fix is obvious: remove that closing brace, so that the boilerplate code is part of the `Solution` class.